# Are there comprehensive lists of polygons for collections of euclidean tilings?

Tags: polygons, tiling

There are large collections of euclidean tilings on the web like [The Tiling Database](http://www.tilingsearch.org/) or on CDROM like 'The World of Patterns' (ISBN-13: 978-9810246198).

Is there a comprehensive list of polygons that are used in such a collection? A superset of polygons where the elements are used in at least one of those tilings?

It is more probable that there are lists for special tiling subsets which would also be helpful. For example the list for [regular ege-to-edge tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons) would be: equilateral triangle, square, regular hexagon, dodecagon.

Background: The underlying task of this question is to identify the polygons in arbitrary tiling images from those collections (or subsets of those collections) with Computer Vision methods. If a superset of polygons is known this could become a manageable classification task.